# How can I scrape label value using prometheus query from metrics and set alerts

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

*How can I scrape label **task_attempt_num** value from below metrics and configure alerts if its greater than 0*

````
flink_taskmanager_numrecordout{instance="eu99",task_attempt_num="2",task_id=2}
flink_taskmanager_numrecordout{instance="eu99",task_attempt_num="0",task_id=2}
flink_taskmanager_numrecordout{instance="eu99",task_attempt_num="1",task_id=1}
flink_taskmanager_numrecordout{instance="eu99",task_attempt_num="0",task_id=3}```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using absent method in Prometheus we can check whether the metric we are searching does exist, if it doesn't exist we will get 1 as output and Null in other case.

Comment: How does that answer your question ? Also note that absent only applies on the selected metric, it cannot tell if a metric is missing on a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get alerted whenever the number of attempts exceeds `0` for a task.

You cannot apply arithmetic operators on labels but you can apply [selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). You can to count the number of attempts that are not `0`:

```
expr: count(flink_taskmanager_numrecordout{task_attempt_num!="0"})  without(task_attempt_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

While Prometheus doesn't provide the functionality for comparing numeric label values, this can be done with [label_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value) function in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). The following query returns non-empty results (e.g. it alerts) when it encounters `flink_taskmanager_numrecordout` time series with `task_attempt_num` label value bigger than 0:

```
label_value(flink_taskmanager_numrecordout, "task_attempt_num") > 0
```